# Alternative to Reactdom.render and unmountComponentAtNode in react18

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, createelement, react-component-unmount

**Important note**:
I am aware of createRoot and root.unmount()! Unfortunately (If I understand this correctly) they should be used just once in the application for mounting the react application.

**Problem description:**
In our app we have a modal component that is rendered dynamically and added to the body of the html via ReactDOM.render(). When this modal is hidden, we unmountComponentAtNode().

Unfortunately, after upgrading to react18, unmountComponentAtNode becomes deprecated and the new unmount is (in my understanding) for the root only. The same problem is about if I try to modify the ReactDOM.Render() for createRoot. Then we would have 2 roots in the app which is wrong.

What is the proper way to attach the modal to the body element (next to root!) and unmount it after it should be destroyed? The implementation is a little bit "weird" (partially in jsx, partially not...) and I would like to avoid refactoring the whole component as there will be a lot of refactoring already in the code... So I would like to focus on refactoring this component (into jsx one) later. Now I have to figure out only the rendering / unmounting. I have been thinking about using Portals, but anyway I have to create that elements somehow and render them into the DOM where portals does not help me a lot.

Calling the createRoot and then render on the root in this modal component fires an error `You are calling ReactDOMClient.createRoot() on a container that has already been passed to createRoot() before. Instead, call root.render() on the existing root instead if you want to update it.` which is obvious. But there is no "useRoot()" hook or anything like that. Should I store the returned object (root) in some context or somewhere to use it later? Or what should be the best option to call the render? :/

I know how I should do that with classical functional component... But maybe there is some way that I can just refactor a piece of the code instead of the whole component and all its usecases. Maybe there is something I am not aware of (there is definitely thousands of things I am not aware of :D) that should simplify my life...

```
function modal() {
  return (
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
  )
}

Modal.show = () => {
  modalEl = document.createElement('div');

  util.destroy(el) => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(el);
    el.remove();
  }

  const childs = props.childs;
  REactDOM.render(childs, modalEl);
}
```

When I was thinking about portals, I thought I will just rewrite the last line of ReactDOM.render to portal like createPortal(childs, modalEl), unfortunately this does not render anything (except modalEl, but no childs inside). The childs are of type ReactNode (using typescript) and they are not empty (because of ReactDOM.render works without any problem).